# Interrupting a ServerSocket#accept() and shutting down a multi-threaded socket server

Tags: java, multithreading, socket, server

I have some code in progress that does multi threaded communication via sockets. I am using a poison pill to shut it down. It is a local port number. Is there a better way to shut it down gracefully?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class MultiThreadedSocketServer {
    private final int listeningPort;
    private final ErrorListener errorListener;
    private final TrafficHandlerFactory trafficHandlerFactory;

    private final AtomicReference<ServerSocket> serverSocket = new AtomicReference<>();
    private final AtomicReference<ExecutorService> executorService = new AtomicReference<>();
    private volatile int poisonLocalPort;
    private final InetAddress localPoisonAddress;

    public MultiThreadedSocketServer(int listeningPort, ErrorListener errorListener, TrafficHandlerFactory trafficHandlerFactory) {
        this.listeningPort = listeningPort;
        this.errorListener = errorListener;
        this.trafficHandlerFactory = trafficHandlerFactory;
        try {
            this.localPoisonAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            errorListener.error(e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        executorService.set(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, new NamedThreadFactory(getClass().getSimpleName())));

        try {
            this.serverSocket.set(new ServerSocket(listeningPort, 0, InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            errorListener.error(e);
            return;
        }

        executorService.get().submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (!executorService.get().isShutdown()) {
                    try {
                        final Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.get().accept();
                        InetSocketAddress remoteSocketAddress = (InetSocketAddress) clientSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress();
                        if (remoteSocketAddress.getPort() == poisonLocalPort && remoteSocketAddress.getAddress().equals(localPoisonAddress)) {
                            errorListener.info("Port " + poisonLocalPort + " was a poison pill. Terminating the server.");
                            clientSocket.close();
                            return;
                        } else {
                            executorService.get().submit(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    try {
                                        TrafficHandler trafficHandler = trafficHandlerFactory.create(clientSocket.getInputStream(), clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                                        trafficHandler.handle();
                                        clientSocket.close();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        errorListener.warning(e);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
    //                        if(executorService.get().isShutdown()) {
    //                            supportTeam.info(getClass().getSimpleName() + " stopped");
    //                        } else {
                        errorListener.error(e);
    //                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (serverSocket.get() == null || serverSocket.get().isClosed()) {
            errorListener.warning("Not started, server: " + serverSocket);
        } else {
            sendPoisonPill();
            shutdownAndAwaitTermination(executorService.get());
            executorService.set(null);
            try {
                serverSocket.get().close();
                serverSocket.set(null);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                errorListener.warning(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendPoisonPill() {
        try {
            // TODO between finding a port and opening a socket some other thread could steal the port, fix it
            poisonLocalPort = findFreePort();
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", listeningPort, localPoisonAddress, poisonLocalPort);
            OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write("poison".getBytes());
            socket.shutdownOutput();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            errorListener.error(e);
        }
    }

    public int findFreePort() {
        int port;
        try {
            ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(0);
            port = socket.getLocalPort();
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            port = -1;
        }
        return port;
    }

    void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
        pool.shutdown();
        try {
            if (!pool.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                pool.shutdownNow();
                if (!pool.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                    errorListener.error(getClass().getSimpleName() + ": Pool did not terminate");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            pool.shutdownNow();
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983835/how-can-i-interrupt-a-serversocket-accept-method

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I tried that before, but I have not found a way to differentiate a genuine I/O error SocketException vs. one triggered by a close(). The documentation does not say if [accept()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29) throws SocketException only and only if [close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#close%28%29) was called.

Comment: I guess I could interrupt the thread that is waiting for connections...?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the problem you're trying to solve is that even after you signal to shut down the server (by setting appropriate state variables), that doesn't stop `serverSocket.accept()`. Is that it?

I could be missing something, but it seems a simple solution could be to create a simple dummy connection as the poison pill. No need to find a free port, just do this:

1. Signal to shut down (so that `executorService.get().isShutdown()` will evaluate to `true` next time around)
2. As the "poison pill", just make a simple connection, `new Socket("localhost", port)`, and throw it away. No need even to write anything on the socket's output stream.

This approach is also not perfect, because another client might still cut in first and connect before your dummy. But that cannot be prevented anyway. This solution is not very different from yours, just simplified, without the step of finding a free port.

---

Another approach can be setting a socket timeout, for example:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
serverSocket.setSoTimeout(SO_TIMEOUT);

while (!stopRequested) {
    try {
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        // ...
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        // accept timed out, continue listening unless stop requested
    }
```

---

... or maybe I completely misunderstood your situation and intentions. I hope this helps. Downvote if it doesn't and I'll delete.